# Jquery with AJAX, not calling the action and not displaying the output. But, able to do with old way without ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

I am using Ajax async to pull one report from db.. I am able to do when i used this code

```
function showCustomer(str)
{
    alert("Report is loading..!Please wait");

var xmlhttp;    
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","Pull.action?rel="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

But when i try to use jquery ajax, i am not able to get the output,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(event){
        $("#submit").hide();
        $('#txtHint').text("Loading..! Please Wait. !!");
        var name = $("#first").name();

        alert(name);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"Pull.action?rel="+name,
             context: document.body,
            success: function(data){
                alert(name);
$('#txtHint').html(data);
                //$('#txtHint').load("Pull.action?rel="+name);
                $("#submit").show();
            }           
        });
    });
 });
```

Am i doing any mistake here, it is not calling that "pull.action" Struts2 action also.

JSP which is using is

```
<form action=""> 
<table><tr><td>
<s:select id="first" label="Please select the Go Live Date : "  name="applicationPhases" value="%{applicationPhases}" headerValue="--Select--"
  list="{'--Select--','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'}" />
</td><td>
<s:submit id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  />  
</td></tr> </table>
</form>
<br /><br />
<br />
<div id="txtHint" />
```

Please help me out to make ajax request using jquery to call one action class from a jsp and display the output in same jsp.. (output will be display-tag table and variable has to be passed through url to action class)

Comment: are you getting error, add this method and check getting error message error : function() {    alert('Error while response..');}

Comment: @pappu_kutty i have tried putting error message. but, it didnt show anything.. Even, i am not getting that alert('name') also..  "Pull.action" class will provide the list which is later displayed in jsp using display-tag

Comment: if you are not getting alert then there might me syntax problem. after launch of the page, if you have chrome or firefox, in chrome press ctrl+shft+j (debug) and see what is the issue.

Comment: do you see any error in console (browser-console) ?

Comment: There was syntax error. Now i am able to call other action from this JSP. But, not able to pass the parameter in request.. Please let me know am i doing any mistake here. Below is the ajax jquery call

Comment: ,$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#report").click(function(event){
     $("#report").hide();
     $('#txtHint').text("Loading..! Please Wait. !!");
     var name = $("#first").val();
     alert(name);
     $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url:"Pull.action","name":name,
      context: document.body,
      success: function(data){
       $('#txtHint').html(data);
       $("#report").show();
      }      
     });
    });
 });  from java , quarter = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getParameter("name");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Jquery ajax helped me to attain my requirement,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#report").click(function(event){
        $("#report").hide();
        $('#txtHint').text("Loading..! Please Wait. !!");
        var name = $("#first").val();
        alert(name);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"Pull.action",
            data:{"name":name},
            context: document.body,
            success: function(data){
                $('#txtHint').html(data);
                $("#report").show();
            }    
    error:function(){
                          $('#txtHint').html(data);
                          alert("Error in pulling details");
                            }
        });
    });
 });
```